# How to remove B-Tree subtree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I am implementing a data structure relying on a B-Tree. I need a method removing a portion of the tree.

Specifically, assume the entries stored in the tree are numbered from 0 to n-1. Given 0 <= i <= j <= n-1, removeSubtree(i,j) should leave a valid B-Tree containing entries 0,..,i-1,j+1,..n-1.

The base case is when both the i-th and the j-th entry are in the same leaf node, which is easy. Assume L_i is the leaf node containing the i-th entry, L_j the leaf node containing the j-th entry, and lca(L_i,L_j) the inner node which is the lowest common ancestor of L_i and L_j. How to proceed then?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what your specific difficulty is, but it's just a special case of the normal deletion process. Delete the key(s), and if that leaves the node too empty rotate elements in from an adjacent node, merging them if necessary, and adjusting the parent node(s) as required.